# I use $.ajax to send data by the way of get, but can not execute the success callback function though I get the success data

Tags: ajax

please click the body details to see the screenshot link.  [this is the code screenshot,when I use the 'post' to send data, the Java can not get the data because they are 'null'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0TnH.jpg)

Comment: You want to use window.location.assign or location.href.  Did you try to use firebug and look at the request and response?

Comment: If you want help on StackOverflow, it is better to post your code in the question, not just a link.

Comment: it seems just skip the code :window.loaction.href @gview

Comment: $.ajax({
    type:"get",
    url:"http://192.168.1.69:8080/adyx/user/insertH5",
    data:{
     "account":isAccount,
     "password":isPassword,
     "payPassword":isPayPassword
    },
    dataType:"json",
    async:false,
    success:function(suc){
     alert(suc);
     window.location.href = "share_success.html";
    },
    error:function(){
     console.log("error");
    } 
   });@radiovisual

Comment: it's looking for http://.... Url's have to be valid.

Comment: I am sorry，it only works in local area network, the code all goes well but the 'window.location.href...' .when alert is over, the function is over,I don't know why, it seems like skip that code, is it  a possible that can't use 'type:get' and 'async:false'@gview

Comment: Update your question with the current code you have.

Answer (score 0):

cause I used  the tag "form"  !!!!
when you use "form" ,you must use the "form 'action='xxxx'  ",I changed the tag "form" to tag "div" ,success!